# MvxDownloadCache while offline

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

MvxImageView work together with MvxDownloadCache.

When the app is used on a device that's offline (airplane mode, no WiFi, etc.), pictures that have very recently been displayed (and thus cached by MvxDownloadCache) appear empty. I assumed the cached image would be displayed when offline. 
Or is a connection to the original (remote) file needed first?

Comment: I use the same way to support the display of cached images when there is no internet connection and I don't have this problem. Which version of MvvmCross & Plugins do you use?

Comment: Do you have loaded the Json-Plugin as described in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks Stefan,

Although both File and Json plugins are used in the project, I only forced File to be loaded before DownloadCache. 
After forcing Json to be EnsureLoaded as well, it all works as expected.

Comment: I will add this as an answer to this question to make it easier for other people :)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that both the JSON and the File-plugin are loaded as well. These plugins are required for the DownloadCache to work correctly.